# .android и .androidStudio какую информацию хранят эти папки, можно ли их перенести на не системный диск

Tags: android-studio

Использую windows 7 , заметил что у меня ряд папок `.android ,  .androidStudio1.4,.androidStudio2.2 , .androidStudio2.3 и .gradle` в совокупности занимают 20 гб.  Хочется узнать сколько же там может быть ненужного. И как часто андроид студио обращается к этим данным (если не часто, то я бы попытался перенести эти папки на другой не SDD диск.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Папка `.android` хранит в себе созданные эмуляторы, кеш и настройки для Android SDK

Папки вида `.AndroidStudioX.Y`/`.AndroidStudioPreviewX.Y` хранят настройки и установленные плагины для соответствующей версии IDE. Если используете только одну версию, то можете смело стирать папки с другой версией. Местоположение данной папки можно настроить, выставив нужный путь в `STUDIO_HOME\bin\idea.properties`

Папка `.gradle` хранит кеш выкачанных библиотек (pom + jar/aar + исходники) и сам Gradle. Обычно это самая увесистая папка, её можно смело удалить и Gradle Wrapper создаст её заново при следующей сборке, выкачав только нужные библиотеки. Местоположение данной папки можно настроить, выставив нужный путь в переменной окружения `GRADLE_USER_HOME`

Comment: хм..у меня есть еще папка sdk, которая по рекомендации установлена в корень диска С, в ней самое увесистое это папка system-images, в которой как раз и находятся образы. Теперь вижу, что эти в папке .android есть эти мои эмуляторы. Правильно ли я понимаю, что если я удалю образы из sdk, то эмуляторы не смогут загрузиться? или же эмуляторы готовы и им больше не нужны образы? (думаю что нужны, судя по тому что образ куда больше весит).

Comment: Говоря кэш выкаченных библиотеку, вы имеете ввиду, что там хранятся исходные коды библиотек? т.е. подключил я библиотеку Jsoup и теперь ее код будет в .gradle ? или  там То что получается при сборке проекта этой библиотеки согласно build.gradle и Это хранится, чтобы при повторном запуске потратить меньше времени?

Comment: Думаю, что не стоит эту папку убирать с ssd диска, так как от этого будет зависеть производительность. А ssd для этого и покупался и нынче они не такие дохлые, как в начале своего пути.

Comment: в system-images хранятся чистые образы, а вот все изменения, внесённые в процессе работы - только в папке avd. Папка .AndroidStudio должна быть на ssd, иначе появятся тормоза в AndroidStudio.